# Derivative of a parsed SymPy expression is always 0

Tags: python, math, sympy

I am writing a program that requires the user to enter an expression. This expression is entered as a string and converted to a Sympy expression using `parse_expr`. I then need to take the partial derivative of that expression that the user entered. However, `diff` is returning 0 with every expression I am testing.

For example if the user enters `a*exp(-b*(x-c)**(2))`, using the following code, `diff` returns `0` when it should (as far as I know about `diff`) return `2*a*b*(c - x)*exp(-b*(x - c)**2)` when taking the partial derivative with respect to `x`:

```
a, b, c, x = symbols('a b c x', real=True)
str_expr = "a*exp(-b*(x-c)**(2))"
parsed_expr = parse_expr(str_expr)
result = diff(parsed_expr, x)
print(result) # prints 0
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bottom line:** use **`parse_expr(str_expr,locals())`**.

Add `global_dict=<dict of allowed entities to use>`, too, if the expression may use any entities not imported into the local namespace and not accessible [with the default `from sympy import *`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr).

---

According to [Calculus — SymPy Tutorial - SymPy 1.0.1.dev documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/calculus.html), you type the symbolic expression into the `diff()` argument as-is. Due to the fact that the letters are `Symbol` objects (with overridden operators), Python is tricked into constructing the SymPy object corresponding to the expression as it evaluates the argument!

Thus, if you have it as a string, you `eval` it to trigger the same behaviour:

```
<...>
>>> s="a*exp(-b*(x-c)**(2))"
>>> diff(eval(s), x)
−ab(−2c+2x)e−b(−c+x)2
```

**But `eval` is a security hazard if used with untrusted input because it accepts arbitrary Python code.**

This is where replacements like [`parse_expr`](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/parsing.html#sympy.parsing.sympy_parser.parse_expr) come into play. However, due to the way expressions are parsed, described above, it needs access to the external entities used in the expression - like the `Symbol` objects for variables and function objects for the named functions used - through the `local_dict` and `global_dict` arguments.

Otherwise, it creates the `Symbol` objects on the fly. Which means, the `Symbol` object it has created for `x` in the expression is different from the variable `x`! No wonder that the derivative over it is 0!

```
<...>
>>> ps=parse_expr(s)
>>> ps.free_symbols
{a,b,c,x}
>>> x in _
False
>>> diff(ps,x)
0

>>> ps=parse_expr(s,locals())
>>> x in ps.free_symbols
True
>>> diff(ps,x)
-ab(−2c+2x)e−b(−c+x)2
```

Answer (score 2):

Work is ongoing to make `sympify` safer than `eval`. Better to use something like the following:

```
from sympy import *

var ('a b c x')

str_expr = "a*exp(-b*(x-c)**(2))"
parsed_expr = sympify(str_expr)
result = diff(parsed_expr, x)
print(result)
```

Result:

```
-a*b*(-2*c + 2*x)*exp(-b*(-c + x)**2)
```

Comment: What's the difference between `sympify` and `parse_expr`? They seem to be doing the same thing. `sympify` even seems less safe because it appears that it just tries to sanitize the string while `parse_expr` is a full-fledged specialized parser.

Comment: I was commenting about the first version of your answer, comparing `sympify` with `eval`. Also, notice that I wrote that the work is *ongoing*. I asked on sympy chat whether `sympify` could be made safer and some effort ensued to accomplish that.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `a, b, c, x = symbols('a b c x', real=True)` with:

```
a = Symbol('a')
b = Symbol('b')
c = Symbol('c')
x = Symbol('x')
```

Comment: It's not the replacement of `symbols`->`Symbol` that made it work. It's the omission of `real=True`. `Symbol('x')` happens to be equal to the `Symbol` object for `x` that `parse_expr` creates implicitly when not passed one in arguments, as described in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43554892/648265).

Comment: So, you were just lucky and this isn't the right way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Symbols with different assumptions compare unequal:

```
>>> Symbol('x') == Symbol('x', real=True)
False
```

When you use `sympify` or `parse_expr`, it parses unknown variables as symbols without assumptions. In your case, this creates `Symbol('x')`, which is considered distinct from the `Symbol('x', real=True)` you already created.

The solution is to either remove the assumptions, or include the `locals()` dictionary when you parse, so that it recognizes the name `x` as being the `Symbol('x', real=True)` that you already defined, like

```
parse_expr(str_expr,locals())
```

or

```
sympify(str_expr, locals())
```